# getting current URL from popup.hml and send it to external.js 

Tags: url, google-chrome, tabs

been searching without finding a solution for me,

I need to be able to send and recive current tab URL when the Chrome extension is shown:

this is My popup.html:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
div, td, th { color: black; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function getURL_please(){
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {    
    return tab.url;
});   
  }
</script>
<script src="http://keepyourlinks.com/API/public/chrome.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 650px;height:600px;margin:0px;paddin:0px;width:100%;">
    <span class="keeper">keep</span>       
</body>
</html>
```

An then, in my webiste, on a chrome.js file i try:

```
$("body").ready(function(){
        var url = getURL_please();
    $(".keeper").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        window.open("http://keepyourlinks.com/API/public/compartir_link.php?url="+url,'about to keep', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=650,height=600');
    });         
});
```

But URL is allways: Undefined

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI Toni,

Google Chrome Extensions use an Asynchronous API,

```
function getURL_please(){
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {    
    return tab.url;
  });   
}
```

The above will always return null. If you want to make it work correctly.

```
function getURL_please(){
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {    
    var url = tab.url;
    // Do what you want here.
  });   
}
```

You would need to the windows open after you you fetch the url. One question though, what do you mean "in your website"? You cannot run Chrome Extension JavaScript directly on your website, so I assume via "Content Script" (most likely, just making sure)?

If your using a Content Script, why would you need to use the Extension API? You can just use `window.location.href`

Comment: no well, i don't need the Extension Api for that, i need that in my extension API aswell. Thanks for your reply i'll try and let you know :)